# Intuition behind View and adapters

Tags: android, listview, adapter

What is the intuition behind views and adapters in Android, that means from where did the person who made this concept get the thought process necessary to create these elements? To elaborate, the concept of circle originated from nature, moon sun such celestial bodies, like wise what is the intuition behind using listview and adapters?

Answer (score 0):

As you probably already know, using ListView (and more recently, RecyclerView) on Android requires the use of an *Adapter* to get the data from the data source and turn it into something displayable which can then then be shown in the list.

So why did the engineers at Google implement ListView and the backing Adapters the way they did ?

It essentially comes to a few things:

- **Performance:**
  Imagine you have 1000 contacts, each with a picture and various pieces of information. You want it to work well, load quickly, and scroll smoothly. The naive way of doing this might be to create a scrollable layout to hold the contacts list, and then simply add a sub-layout for each contact. Unfortunately, this will fail all three requirements: It won't work well, as there won't be enough memory (ram) for all those contacts and especially the associated pictures, and the app will run out of memory and crash; It won't load quickly, as all the contacts and the contact pictures have to be loaded into memory before the list can be shown, which will take a long time; And it won't scroll smoothly because you don't have all of the advanced caching, pre-rendering, and bitmap texture caching that ListView and the adapter does. Use a ListView and an Adapter, and it solves all these problems for you.
- **Adaptability and ease of use for developers:** ListView and Adapters are used for lots of different things, from contacts lists all the way to to complex pages with different answers, comments, and tons of other information in the Stack Exchange Android app. Adapters make working with data from different sources easy: there's a single, common API, which can be used and extended to display any kind of data, much more easily than if every developer had to implement their own solution. Want to load more data when the user has scrolled to the bottom of your list ? Sure, it's easy. Want to have different kinds of items in your list ? Sure, It's really easy.

So, did Google and the Android developers and engineers invent this idea of using adapters ? No.

In fact almost every system or environment which involves showing a list of items uses something similar: The actual list of items, an Adapter behind it, to transform the data and make it displayable, and then the actual data source, which can be anything which gives a list of items, from a database to a web service. It's essentially this: `data source > adapter > list where it's displayed`. This kind of pattern is used in desktop Windows applications, on iOS, web applications, so the Google engineers took this concept and adapted it to Android.

That's why ListView and Adapters work (and are used) the way they do.

PS: here's a Google IO video by the Google engineers on how to use ListView and Adapters correctly, and a little bit on how they work under the hood: http://youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70.

Comment: Pretty much everything to say. I had kept it shorter and just said: "When implementing the ListView, you don't know what later the data will be."... 